# Allow Directory in local network and only virtual host in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nextcloud

I have installed a nextcloud on my raspberrypi. I want to use it in my local network for file transfer and everywhere for contacts and the calendar.

My nextcloud is located at `/var/www/html/nextcloud`. I also created a file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/nextcloud.conf` to enable the virtual host. Basically:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nextcloud/
  ServerName  nextcloud.example.com

  <Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>

  SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/nextcloud
  SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/nextcloud
</VirtualHost>
```

The nextcloud is reachable for the following links:

- `192.168.2.100/nextcloud`
- `nextcloud.example.com`
- `example.com/nextcloud`

My question: Is there a way to forbid the access via `example.com/nextcloud`?

I tried to add `deny, allow` entries into `/var/www/html/nextcloud/.htaccess`. But either I block too much, or it does not work. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `example.com/nextcloud` is accessible at all is because you're pointing the subdomain at a subdirectory off the main domain's document root (as defined in the main domain's VirtualHost). If the subdomain is an entirely separate entity then it would be preferable that it points to an area outside of the main domain's document root.

> I tried to add deny, allow entries into `/var/www/html/nextcloud/.htaccess`

If you want to block this in `.htaccess` (as opposed to the main domain's vHost config) then you need to check the requested `Host` header. And in doing this I would have thought it would be preferable to block anything other than the canonical hostname, ie. anything other that `nextcloud.example.com` (so it also blocks requests via the IP address). Rather than checking for the hostnames you want to block. You can do this using mod_rewrite, for example:

```
# /var/www/html/nextcloud/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^nextcloud\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above responds with a "403 Forbidden" for any request where the requested `Host` header is *not* (as denoted by the `!` prefix) `nextcloud.example.com`.

You could also block this subdirectory in the main domain's vHost container (not the subdomain). So it only applies to requests to `example.com`. For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Note that `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` are Apache 2.2 directives and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4. You should be using `Require` (mod_authz_core) on Apache 2.4.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your solution, cause it didn't work for me. But your last proposal brought me on the right track. I used `<Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud>Require ip 192.168.2.0/24</Directory>` in the vHost. And it blocks everything for the folder other than my local network.

Comment: @Christian "it didn't work" - What do you mean exactly? Did you get an error? Everything blocked? Nothing blocked? Is mod_rewrite installed? Make sure you are not seeing cached responses. Your solution would still allow access via `example.com/nextcloud`?

Comment: It blocked too much or did not block. I also emptied the cache. `a2enmod rewrite` was activated and I guess nextcloud also uses mod_rewrite, so it should have been there, although I did not check it specifically. The current solution does not allow `example.com/nextcloud`, cause all `example.com` will not use the local ip range, but the router ip.